# Encoding issues request results

Tags: python, python-3.x

im learning python, and im trying to retrieve data from wikipedia, but is giving me encoding issues on special charecters of the links, text, etc:

My code:

```
import sys
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jair_Bolsonaro")



bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html)

for link in bsObj.findAll("a"):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        print(link.attrs['href'])
```

result:

```
/wiki/Hamilton_Mour%C3%A3o
/wiki/Michel_Temer
/wiki/C%C3%A2mara_dos_Deputados_do_Brasil
...

Should be:
    /wiki/Hamilton_Mourão
    /wiki/Michel_Temer
    /wiki/Câmara_dos_Deputados_do_Brasil
    ...
```

Comment: What is the issue? That all looks correct to me.

Comment: Just use `urllib.parse.unquote()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i updated my question

Comment: Why do you believe *it should* be that. Look at the source code of the page you are parsing. You will see that it is exactly what is there. What is going on is called "url encoding", which is done to *avoid* encoding issues in html links. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: @Samuel thanks Samuel it worked

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
import urllib.parse
```

And in print line changed to:

```
 print(urllib.parse.unquote(link.attrs['href']))
```